# When mirroring accounts for Sql Server Windows Authentication, do both have to be local?

Tags: sql-server, authentication, active-directory

I understand that when using windows authentication to connect to a remote SQL Server instance, two local accounts with the same username and password can be used (i.e. "mirrored" local accounts).

My question is: if the username and password are the same, can the client account be a domain account and the SQL Server account be a local account?